# can I load a configSource and then add additional keys in web.config

Tags: iis, web-config

I have some individual settings I need to apply to specific web sites, and I have a slew of settings that are shared across the websites. I deploy via a continuous integration system.

In my `web.config` file I have :

```
<appSettings configSource="App_Data\thisSiteSettings.xml" >
    <clear />
    <add key="AllSitesSetting" value="ForAllSites" />
</appSettings >
```

What happens is I get just the settings from thisSiteSettings.xml, and none of the settings from the web.config. I also tried having 2 sections:

```
<appSettings >
    <clear />
    <add key="AllSitesSetting" value="ForAllSites" />
</appSettings >

<appSettings configSource="App_Data\thisSiteSettings.xml" >
</appSettings >
```

which just threw an Error. Finally I tried including the configsource as an "add" node, but that just threw an error as well. (`<add configSource="thisSiteSettings.xml" />`)

How can I load a few site specific app settings from a seperate file, and the rest from the web.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<appSettings file="thisSiteSettings.xml">
    ...
<appSettings />
```

appSettings in the external file will override settings with the same key in the main configuration file.

Comment: deleted my previous comment as I copied the file attribute into the file